# Kotlin declare list of same values of fixed size

Tags: list, kotlin

Is it possible to declare a list of same values of fixed size in **Kotlin**. For example, if the value is 1 and the size is 5. I want to declare a list which would look like below:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I know I can declare a mutable list, and then populate it with 1's. But is there any shortcut?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just specify the amount of items and the value of each item like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // specify the list size
    val n = 5
    // specify the item value
    val v = 1
    // create a list of size n with v as each value
    var myList = MutableList(n) {v}
    // print it
    println(myList)
}
```

The output is then

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

easier solution for this, (just as @deHaar answer but immutable one)

```
List(5) { 1 }

// -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using range operator and map function

```
    (1..5).map { 1 })
```